# Keras Multi Label Classification Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I've implemented a multi-label MLP in Keras with tensorflow and I'm trying to perform data augmentation with Keras Image Data Generators as below.

However, I am outputting multiple labels for y (predicting both age AND gender with a branched network of two outputs, one input (the image)).

In order to do this, I found online one has to create a wrapper as the image generator can only take single arrays as a parameter, which I have done.

The problem is, the generators suggest the images belong to 97 classes and 90 classes respectively, whereas for age I would not like each age to be a separate class. I believe this is causing problem later when fitting my model.

Though the model seems to undergo training (for a few minutes only) there is no significant output and I cannot see how to make this type of model with data augmentation, when there are multiple labels involved. Any suggestions?

Code for data generators:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    fill_mode = 'nearest'
    )

test_datagen= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = df_train,
x_col="image",
y_col="labels",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
target_size=(128, 128))


valid_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = df_test,
x_col = "image",
y_col = "labels",
batch_size = 32,
seed = 42,
shuffle = True,
target_size=(128, 128))
```

**Dataframe of training data (2 columns, image column slightly hidden with path name and second column is array of labels, index 0 denoting age and index 1 denoting gender:**

[image: Dataframe of training data (2 columns, image column slightly hidden with path name and second column is array of labels, index 0 denoting age and index 1 denoting gender]

**Model creation and wrapper function below. Note the images are 128 x 128 color images from the UTK face dataset (4000 training images, 1000 validation).**

```
#model creation 
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)

inputs = Input((input_shape))
# convolutional layers
conv_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu') (inputs)
maxp_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (conv_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu') (maxp_1)
maxp_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (conv_2)
conv_3 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu') (maxp_2)
maxp_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (conv_3)
conv_4 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu') (maxp_3)
maxp_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (conv_4)

flatten = Flatten() (maxp_4)

# fully connected layers
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu') (flatten)
dense_2 = Dense(256, activation='relu') (flatten)

dropout_1 = Dropout(0.3) (dense_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.3) (dense_2)

output_1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='gender_out') (dropout_1)
output_2 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='age_out') (dropout_2)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[output_1, output_2])

model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mae'], optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'mae'])

model = Model(inputs=input,outputs=[age_l,gender_l])
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss=["mse","binary_crossentropy"],metrics=['mae','accuracy'])

def generator_wrapper(generator):
    for batch_x, batch_y in generator:
        yield (batch_x, [batch_y[:, i] for i in range(2)])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size

history = model.fit(generator_wrapper(train_generator),
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, validation_data=generator_wrapper(valid_generator),
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,epochs=1,verbose=2)
```

Comment: I remember there was a `class_mode = 'categorical'` to add in the data generator ig. This is for multilabel data.

Comment: Thanks - so even though age is not categorical but gender is, I should be using categorical class mode? I did see that but wasn't sure how to incorporate it given both labels are not categorical.

Comment: For gender you'll prolly have to keep `class_mode='binary'`, just specify the `y_col` accordingly. Age is a continuous variable so it becomes a regression task, i'm not sure how that works here but you can check [this](https://gist.github.com/conormm/5b26a08029b900520bcd6fcd1f5712a0)

Comment: Hmm, well my model is branched so without the regularization I can do both tasks in one model (with multiple outputs) but that's what I'm finding tricky with the data augmentation how to do it in one model without separating into 2 tasks